# How to make table in gifted chat module react-native

Tags: react-native

I'm using react-native and i have gifted chat messanger system (Bot type ) in which bot ask me questions and i'll give answers to them.My requirement is that i have to give answer in chat messenger in the form of table in which only show 3 rows.But, in my senirio i'm trying to use this code like this

```
{
      question: "Please fill up the ASCI mining hardware details here.",
      responseType: "table",
      id: "miner",
      include: ["miner"],
      columns: [
        {
          label: "First name",
          id: "firstName",
          responseLength: 60,
          responseType: ["string"]
        },
        {
          label: "Last name",
          id: "lastName",
          responseLength: 60,
          responseType: ["string"]
        },
        {
          label: "NRIC/FIN or Passport",
          id: "idNumber",
          responseType: "string"
        },
        {
          label: "Date of birth",
          id: "DOB",
          responseType: "date",
          pastOnly: true
        },
        {
          label: "Gender",
          id: "gender",
          responseType: ["choice", "number"],
          choices: [{ label: "Male", value: 1 }, { label: "Female", value: 2 }]
        },
        {
          label: "Relationship",
          id: "relationship",
          responseType: ["choice", "number"],
          choices: [{ label: "Spouse", value: 1 }, { label: "Child", value: 2 }]
        }
      ]
    },
```

So this will pop up a table like this.But its doesn't work for me

Comment: Can you please clarify the question. I can't follow what you want. Do you want the text input to be a table or do you want the table to show up instead of the bubble?